# How to Extend CErrorHandler?

Tags: php, yii

I want to use my custom ErrorHandler class. I changed the following in config/main.php:

```
'errorHandler'=>array(
        'errorAction'=>'site/error',           
        'class' => 'application.components.CMyErrorHandler',
 ),
```

But haven't had any success in doing so, Yii aparently keeps using the old CErrorHandler class.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your CMyErrorHandler class under the protected/components folder. Here is how you extend the CErrorHandler Class

```
//CMyErrorHandler.php in protected/components folder
class CMyErrorHandler extends CErrorHandler {
    //Class Code
}
```

Comment: Thanks I already did that